# Remove key-value pair based on grouping from dictionaries in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, grouping, key-value

I have a JSON file A.json which contains multiple dictionaries. And I want to remove common key-value pairs from key "model" `grouped by brand`.

For example, consider the brand: "Ford":

```
{"Number": '123', "brand": "Ford", "model":{"Mustang1":"2.64", "Mustang2":"3.00", "Mustang3":"1.00", "Mustang4":"1.64"}}

{"Number": '891', "brand": "Ford", "model":{"Mustang1":"2.64", "Mustang8":"3.00", "Mustang3":"1.00", "Mustang6":"1.64"}}
```

Keys in key `model` which are common across both the dictionaries are `Mustang1` and `Mustang3`. So I removed both of the key-value pair from model.
Final dictionaries would be:

```
 {"Number": '123', "brand": "Ford", "model":{"Mustang2":"3.00", "Mustang4":"1.64"}}
{"Number": '891', "brand": "Ford", "model":{"Mustang8":"3.00", "Mustang6":"1.64"}}
```

A.json

```
{"Number": '123', "brand": "Ford", "model":{"Mustang1":"2.64", "Mustang2":"3.00", "Mustang3":"1.00", "Mustang4":"1.64"}}
{"Number": '321', "brand": "Toyota", "model":{"Camry":"2.64", "Prius":"3.00", "Corolla":"1.00", "Tundra":"1.64"}}
{"Number": '111', "brand": "Honda", "model":{"Accord":"2.64", "Civic":"3.00", "Insight":"1.00", "Pilot":"1.64"}}
{"Number": '891', "brand": "Ford", "model":{"Mustang1":"2.64", "Mustang8":"3.00", "Mustang3":"1.00", "Mustang6":"1.64"}}
{"Number": '745', "brand": "Toyota", "model":{"Camry":"2.64", "Sienna":"3.00", "4Runner":"1.00", "Prius":"1.64"}}
{"Number": '325', "brand": "Honda", "model":{"Accord":"2.64", "Passport":"3.00", "HR-V":"1.00", "Pilot":"1.64"}}
{"Number": '745', "brand": "Accura", "model":{"TLX":"2.64", "MDX":"3.00"}}
{"Number": '325', "brand": "Accura", "model":{"TLX":"2.64", "MDX":"3.00"}}
```

Expected Result:
Result.json

```
{"Number": '123', "brand": "Ford", "model":{"Mustang2":"3.00", "Mustang4":"1.64"}}
{"Number": '321', "brand": "Toyota", "model":{"Corolla":"1.00", "Tundra":"1.64"}}
{"Number": '111', "brand": "Honda", "model":{"Civic":"3.00", "Insight":"1.00", "Pilot":"1.64"}}
{"Number": '891', "brand": "Ford", "model":{"Mustang8":"3.00", "Mustang6":"1.64"}}
{"Number": '745', "brand": "Toyota", "model":{"Sienna":"3.00", "4Runner":"1.00"}}
{"Number": '325', "brand": "Honda", "model":{"Passport":"3.00", "HR-V":"1.00", "Civic Type R":"1.64"}}
{"Number": '745', "brand": "Accura", "model":{}}
{"Number": '325', "brand": "Accura", "model":{}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `A.json` is not a regular json file. Here's the corrected version:

```
[{"Number": "123", "brand": "Ford", "model":{"Mustang1":"2.64", "Mustang2":"3.00", "Mustang3":"1.00", "Mustang4":"1.64"}},
{"Number": "321", "brand": "Toyota", "model":{"Camry":"2.64", "Prius":"3.00", "Corolla":"1.00", "Tundra":"1.64"}},
{"Number": "111", "brand": "Honda", "model":{"Accord":"2.64", "Civic":"3.00", "Insight":"1.00", "Pilot":"1.64"}},
{"Number": "891", "brand": "Ford", "model":{"Mustang1":"2.64", "Mustang8":"3.00", "Mustang3":"1.00", "Mustang6":"1.64"}},
{"Number": "745", "brand": "Toyota", "model":{"Camry":"2.64", "Sienna":"3.00", "4Runner":"1.00", "Prius":"1.64"}},
{"Number": "325", "brand": "Honda", "model":{"Accord":"2.64", "Passport":"3.00", "HR-V":"1.00", "Pilot":"1.64"}},
{"Number": "745", "brand": "Accura", "model":{"TLX":"2.64", "MDX":"3.00"}},
{"Number": "325", "brand": "Accura", "model":{"TLX":"2.64", "MDX":"3.00"}}]
```

The content of the file should be parsed with the `json` module:

```
import io # to test without a file
f = io.StringIO(json_text) # json_text is a string containing the text above

import json
ds = json.load(f)
```

Second, you have to build a `set` of common models by brand:

```
common_by_brand = {}
for d in ds:
    if d["brand"] in common_by_brand:
        common_by_brand[d["brand"]] &= set(d["model"])
    else:
        common_by_brand[d["brand"]] = set(d["model"])
    # {'Ford': {'Mustang1', 'Mustang3'}, 'Toyota': {'Camry', 'Prius'}, 'Honda': {'Accord', 'Pilot'}, 'Accura': {'TLX', 'MDX'}}
```

Third, just iterate over the list and remove those common models:

```
for d in ds:
    common = common_by_brand[d["brand"]]
    d["model"] = {k: v for k, v in d["model"].items() if k not in common}
# [{'Number': '123', 'brand': 'Ford', 'model': {'Mustang2': '3.00', 'Mustang4': '1.64'}}, {'Number': '321', 'brand': 'Toyota', 'model': {'Corolla': '1.00', 'Tundra': '1.64'}}, {'Number': '111', 'brand': 'Honda', 'model': {'Civic': '3.00', 'Insight': '1.00'}}, {'Number': '891', 'brand': 'Ford', 'model': {'Mustang8': '3.00', 'Mustang6': '1.64'}}, {'Number': '745', 'brand': 'Toyota', 'model': {'Sienna': '3.00', '4Runner': '1.00'}}, {'Number': '325', 'brand': 'Honda', 'model': {'Passport': '3.00', 'HR-V': '1.00'}}, {'Number': '745', 'brand': 'Accura', 'model': {}}, {'Number': '325', 'brand': 'Accura', 'model': {}}]
```

Fourth, write the result in json format to a file:

```
g = io.StringIO()
json.dump(ds, g)
print (g.getvalue())
```

Formatted output :

```
[{"Number": "123", "brand": "Ford", "model": {"Mustang2": "3.00", "Mustang4": "1.64"}},
{"Number": "321", "brand": "Toyota", "model": {"Corolla": "1.00", "Tundra": "1.64"}},
{"Number": "111", "brand": "Honda", "model": {"Civic": "3.00", "Insight": "1.00"}},
{"Number": "891", "brand": "Ford", "model": {"Mustang8": "3.00", "Mustang6": "1.64"}},
{"Number": "745", "brand": "Toyota", "model": {"Sienna": "3.00", "4Runner": "1.00"}},
{"Number": "325", "brand": "Honda", "model": {"Passport": "3.00", "HR-V": "1.00"}},
{"Number": "745", "brand": "Accura", "model": {}},
{"Number": "325", "brand": "Accura", "model": {}}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was not sure how to get the common keys across the dictionary. This is great!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to load the json in python with the [json builtin library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Then, there are a few ways to achieve this. For example, you could iterate over each dict and update a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) at each iteration. Then you remove every key which has been counted more than once.

Finally, you use the `json` lib again to dump the resulting dict in a new file.

Comment: I think Counter approach would not work here. Because we need to count the keys in key "model" grouped by "brand". For example if brand is "Ford" then remove keys from key model which is common across the dictionary having "brand" value Ford.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you will be using the standard `JSON` format. You need to check when the `type` of `value` for a `key` inside a dictionary is of type `dict`. `isinstance()` method can be used for this purpose. You can use the following code snippet:

```
for key,value in your_json.items():
    if isinstance(value, dict):
       your_json[key]={}
```

I hope this might work.
Cheers :)